# Google Tag Manager click id event not firing

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have set up my element in such a way that google tag manager should fire a tag when I click this element. However, I can not get it to work, eventhough everything should be set up correctly.

I tried multiple things, but I ended with two methods where atleast one should work:

[image: first method]
[image: second method]

However, both method won't work. I added screenshots of the tag manager debugger to illustrate the click event, the tag which should fire and the variables of the event.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition works, when you chose Click Element instead of Click ID.
Click Element has to be activated as it is one of GTMs integrated variables.

The second one works by deleting the quotation marks.